# Convert multiple select boxes on same page to multiple ul

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a webshop with a product list where the variants only can be output as a select box.

I would like to have these select boxes shows as text or ul/li instead.

```
<div class="stock proid">
    <Select class="ProductListVariantSelector" id="ProductListVariantSelector" onchange="ProductListVariantSelectorChange(this);">
        <option></option>
        <option value="/shop/basic-body-ls-3097p.html">0-6 mdr.</option>
        <option value="/shop/basic-body-ls-3098p.html">12-18 mdr.</option>
        <option value="/shop/basic-body-ls-3099p.html">18-24 mdr.</option>
        <option value="/shop/basic-body-ls-3100p.html">6-12 mdr.</option>
    </Select>
</div>
<div class="stock proid">
    <Select class="ProductListVariantSelector" id="ProductListVariantSelector" onchange="ProductListVariantSelectorChange(this);">
        <option></option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2678p.html">56</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2681p.html">74</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2683p.html">86</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2684p.html">92</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2685p.html">98</option>
    </Select>
</div>
<div class="stock proid">
    <Select class="ProductListVariantSelector" id="ProductListVariantSelector" onchange="ProductListVariantSelectorChange(this);">
        <option></option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2603p.html">62</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2604p.html">68</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2605p.html">74</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2606p.html">80</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2607p.html">86</option>
        <option value="/shop/bodystocking-med-lange-2608p.html">92</option>
    </Select>
</div>
```

Can anyone help with that?!

Thanks

Comment: If I understand corectly you just want to transform `seelct` to `ul` and `option` to `li` ? Do you have any code so far?

Comment: Help? Yes. Do it all for your? No. What have you tried? What's causing you problems? Are you using an open-source cart platform or a custom, in-house solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will convert the select boxes to unordered lists for you...

```
$(function() {
    $("select.ProductListVariantSelector").each(function() {
        var $ul = $("<ul/>");
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
            if (this.text !== "") {
                $ul.append($("<li/>", { text: this.text }));
            }
        });
        $(this).replaceWith($ul);
    });
});
```

It also removes the empty items as I assume they were just there for default choices in the selects.

**[working jsfiddle example...](http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/XyfwZ/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select').replaceWith(function () {
    var $opt = $(this).find('option[value]'),
        newhtml = '<ul id="' + this.id + '" class="' + this.className + '">';
    $opt.each(function (_, o) {
        newhtml += '<li data-val="' + o.value + '">' + o.innerHTML + '</li>';
    });
    return newhtml += '</ul>'
});
```

Comment: Perfect... your solution also just works perfect!